# order api search criteria

Tags: orders, rest-api, search-criteria

I have two magento accounts and i am fetching order with below route :

> ("/rest/V1/customers/search?searchCriteria[page_size]=20000&searchCriteria[current_page]=1&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=created_at&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=#{start_time}&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=from&searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][1][field]=created_at&searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][1][value]=#{end_time}&searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][1][condition_type]=to")

my issue is i am not getting six months old order data in one of my account whereas with same search criteria i am getting orders .

Thanks!

Comment: "{\"messages\":{\"error\":[{\"code\":500,\"message\":\"Server internal error. See details in report api\\/472104827965\"}]}}" . i am getting this error